# Cannot load C++/CLI dll if it uses OpenMP

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++, c++-cli, openmp

I had a "Could not load file or assembly '***.dll' or one of its dependencies." on a C++/CLI dll called from a C# program. I eventually nailed this down to the use of a `#pragma omp` directive. If I remove all openmp directives and build, the assembly can be loaded. As soon as I add a single openmp directive, I get this exception. Of course, the compiler option openmp was enabled.

This is on Visual Studio 2012 using the .NET 3.5 framework. Is there anything I can do to make this work? This is performance-critical code that has to compile with OpenMP. I have, by the way, tried to isolate this code into a separate native .lib and include that in the C++/CLI, to no avail.

Comment: openmp requires a support DLL, vcomp110d.dll for the debug build.  It depends on the VS edition whether you have it, you forgot to mention it.  SysInternals' ProcMon can tell you about missing DLLs.

Comment: Looking at the dll in ndepend, I saw that vcomp90d.dll was indeed the only difference in dependencies between a version with openmp and one without. How is this dll supposed to be found by the process and how is it failing?

Comment: vcomp90d.dll is the openmp support library for VS2008.  You said you had VS2012.  Not good.  You still did not mention what edition.

Comment: The project uses the .NET framework 3.5 and the v90 (vs2008) toolset. The edition of Visual Studio is 2012 Ultimate Update 2.

Comment: This is like using the PPL. It's not supported.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558347/how-can-i-mix-the-concurrency-runtime-with-net-code

Comment: In that question you link to, the only information regarding OpenMP is that it *is* supported: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4107242/154766